# controlling better a viewcontroller

Tags: xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller

[image: uinaviguation controller issue]

As shown in the image, I have a view 1 in the buttom containing cutom buttons, just to move from some views like tabbar, and in the first "tab" I have some buttons also, wich should push some views.

My problem is that when I add the naviguation controller and I push a view, I get all the view moving, including the buttom view 1. I just want it to move only for the upper views.

I tired to add the naviguation controller to the first upper view, but still not working.

Any help please ?

Comment: Why using navigation controller ? Why not just remove the previous view and add a new one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UINavigationController (and indeed, the whole view controller architecture) doesn't support swapping out just some subviews. It works with UITabBarController because the tab bar controller contains the navigation controller. You really don't have that option.

Two options that might help are:

1. Add separate instances of your "view 1" to both "view 2" and "view 3".
2. Abandon UINavigationController and manage the transition from "view 2" to "view 3" yourself. Animating the transition isn't difficult, but straying from the recommended view controller architecture makes this a bit of an advanced topic.

Comment: THanks for you all, in the case that I want to abandon INavigationController and manage the transition in myself, How should I do that ? Is it just like this :

view2=view3; ?

Comment: One way to do it is to send the container view a `-addSubview:` message specifying view 3. Make sure that view 3 will be positioned offscreen, probably to the right of view 2. Then use Core Animation to move both views to the left, so that view 2 disappears and view 3 appears on screen. Finally, send view 2 a `-removeFromSuperview` message to remove it from the view hierarchy. Note that both views 2 and 3 will be managed by the same view controller.

Answer (score 0):

If those are two separate UIViewControllers
You can try to remove the button view1 and allocate new one on the next view.

```
[self.view1 removeFromSuperview];
```

if it is done as two UIViews in one class you can do the same, but without allocating the new button, just:

```
[self.view3 bringSubviewToFront:view1];
```